# Neural nets for ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, backpropagation

Which libraries/plugins are the best(fast/well-documented/etc) for designing and creating neural nets with backpropgation?
Googling
[Ai4r](http://ai4r.rubyforge.org/)
[Ai-Appp](http://ai-app-prog.rubyforge.org/)

Answer (score 1):

ruby-fann is the way to go, I think.  It's fast and stable and easy to use.  You can find it [here](http://ruby-fann.rubyforge.org/).